# How to scope the reset CSS so that is applied to Ext components using scopeResetCSS property?

Tags: extjs4

How can I set Ext CSS to be just applied to Ext components?

This is what is mentioned in Ext documentation for `scopeResetCSS`:

```
scopeResetCSS : Boolean
True to scope the reset CSS to be just applied to Ext components. 
Note that this wraps root containers with an additional element. 
Also remember that when you turn on this option, you have to use ext-all-scoped 
{ unless you use the bootstrap.js to load your javascript, in which case it will be 
handled for you.
```

I have already set `Ext.scopeResetCSS=true;` & also Replaced the `ext-all.css` with `ext-all-scoped.css`, but that does not help.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Donald Sipe for posting the solution for this in his [blog](http://www.djsipe.com/2011/07/08/scoping-extjs-css/).

You should create Ext object in the following manner before it is loaded by `ext-debug.js` script:

```
 <script>
    // Here we define Ext for the first time
    Ext = {
        buildSettings:{
            "scopeResetCSS": true  // Thanks, but I'll do my own scoping please
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="js/libs/ext/4.0.2a/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

By setting the `scopeResetCSS` value in `buildSettings` config object, you are telling ExtJS that you are going to handle CSS scoping all by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

For example, to get a scoped version the gray theme:

1. install [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)
2. Then, on command line, move to the ExtJs Sass folder e.g. `/extjs/resources/sass`
3. duplicate the file `ext-all-gray.scss`
4. add the line `$scope-reset-css: true;` at the top of the file.

Then run: `compass compile ext-all-gray-scoped.scss`

This will create a file `ext-all-gray-scoped.css` in the CSS folder which you can now use.