# Having css troubles with adding Gantt chart as JIRA report

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, jira, gantt-chart

I am using this library for Gantt:

http://www.bryntum.com/examples/gantt-latest/examples/basic/basic.html

When I implement it **as JIRA report**, the left bar in JIRA gets moved to middle.

[image]*Images are for illustrative purposes only.*

I researched and found the problem was in Gantt library CSS file:

http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css

Don't try to understand it, it has 10000 lines after beautifying the code. But after debugging I found the solution. When removing this code, the JIRA left bar moved to left and everything looked fine:

```
.x-border-box,.x-border-box * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Except:

[image]*Images are for illustrative purposes only.*

The footer moved on top of the Gantt Chart. So having the second option is better, but I still prefer having my footer down below.

I tried changing CSS values, but could not produce any other results, than these two shown on screenshots.

**So all in all, how do I get the footer down and the JIRA bar to left.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Ext JS CSS is global on the page, conflicting with other elements. This post might help, and helps set the 'scope' of the CSS to any element on the page - like your Gantt chart container div etc.

[How to scope the reset CSS so that is applied to Ext components using scopeResetCSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435833/how-to-scope-the-reset-css-so-that-is-applied-to-ext-components-using-scopereset)

Use:

```
Ext = {buildSettings: {scopeResetCSS: true}};
```

together with ext-all-scoped.css. Should do it.

Comment: It was said that it only works with 4.0.2 and lower. But you only have new versions on your webpage, old links are broken. Can you give me links for archived versions?

Comment: The solution you gave me, there is link with more info and look comments there : http://blog.djsipe.com/2011/07/08/scoping-extjs-css/  , It is said, that it will not work with new Ext JS.

Comment: See my response here, that might help: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?181012-How-to-disable-Ext-JS-polluting-HTML-with-extra-class-ID-attributes

Comment: Didn't you read my first post, I told you, I removed the x-border-box manually from css, and it makes the same thing, as your command. It made everything look better, except 2 bugs: Footers jumps to top, as I described on the first post, arrows do not have inside colored, only 2 lines and arrow head.

Comment: Do you have this available online anywhere so I can inspect it?