# Which is the right way to set ExtJS 4.2 in scope CSS mode?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

It seems that ExtJS 4.2 doesn't include scoped CSS. So, when I apply ExtJS to render a grid, my page look gets ruined. 
I've checked this link: [How to scope the reset CSS so that is applied to Ext components using scopeResetCSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435833/how-to-scope-the-reset-css-so-that-is-applied-to-ext-components-using-scopereset)

I wonder if there is a way of make a scope reset CSS or any method to do what I want in ExtJS 4.2.

Comment: Did you find the solution to your question?

Answer (score 2):

@Sencha explains the fix in [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?260608-New-theme-CSS-breaks-other-CSS-on-the-page) link.

```
ExtJs v4.1.1 or v4.2.1
    Ext = {
            buildSettings:{
            baseCSSPrefix: 'x-',
            scopeResetCSS: true                
        }
    };

ExtJs v4.2.0
    Ext.define('Ext.BorderBoxFix', {
        override: 'Ext.AbstractComponent',


        initStyles: function(targetEl) {
            this.callParent(arguments);


            if (Ext.isBorderBox && (!me.ownerCt || me.floating)) {
                targetEl.addCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'border-box');
            }
        }
    });


    Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.fly(document.documentElement).removeCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'border-box');
    });
```